# matplotlib not showing graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have written this code to show a line graph but the plot is not showing up. The window opens and shows the labels and axis but no plot. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it's a small mistake that I'm overlooking

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("passing_stats_1970_2016.csv", index_col=0)
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Season'])]

# print(qb_data.head())

avg_td = df.groupby('Season').TD.mean()


# setting up seaborn, creating white background
sns.set_style("white")

# setting height to 12, width to 9
plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

# getting x and y values
x_values = df.Season.unique()
y_values = avg_td


# title
title = ("Average TD by season")

#Label y axis
plt.ylabel('Avg TDs', fontsize=18)

#Limit range of axis labels to only show where data is
plt.xlim(1966, 2014.5)
plt.ylim(0,0.08)

# create dashed lines
plt.grid(axis='y',color='grey', linestyle='--', lw=0.5, alpha=0.5)

# Change the size of tick labels for both axis
# to a more readable font size
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)

# get rid of borders for our graph using seaborn's
# despine function
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

# plot the line for our graph
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

plt.text(1966, -0.012,
         'Primary Data Source: http://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/'
         '\nAuthor: Joe T',
          fontsize=12)

# Display graph
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get when I print the x and y values:

```
[ 1970.  1971.  1972.  1973.  1974.  1975.  1976.  1977.  1978.  1979.
  1980.  1981.  1982.  1983.  1984.  1985.  1986.  1987.  1988.  1989.
  1990.  1991.  1992.  1993.  1994.  1995.  1996.  1997.  1998.  1999.
  2000.  2001.  2002.  2003.  2004.  2005.  2006.  2007.  2008.  2009.
  2010.  2011.  2012.  2013.  2014.  2015.]

Season    
1970.0    11.625000
1971.0     9.971429
1972.0    11.645161
1973.0     9.444444
1974.0     8.947368
1975.0    11.545455
1976.0    10.750000
1977.0     9.750000
1978.0    13.090909
1979.0    15.212121
1980.0    16.194444
1981.0    13.700000
1982.0     9.700000
1983.0    15.026316
1984.0    13.658537
1985.0    13.093023
1986.0    13.048780
1987.0    12.121951
1988.0    11.931818
1989.0    14.297297
1990.0    14.486486
1991.0    12.153846
1992.0    11.285714
1993.0    11.068182
1994.0    12.813953
1995.0    15.317073
1996.0    13.431818
1997.0    13.088889
1998.0    12.812500
1999.0    12.775510
2000.0    13.886364
2001.0    15.810811
2002.0    14.755556
2003.0    13.276596
2004.0    17.050000
2005.0    13.311111
2006.0    13.666667
2007.0    13.294118
2008.0    15.073171
2009.0    15.288889
2010.0    16.204545
2011.0    16.204545
2012.0    18.871795
2013.0    17.863636
2014.0    18.428571
2015.0    18.409091
Name: TD, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Are you able to save your plot? Try replacing `plt.show()` with `plt.savefig('image.png')` and see if the intended plot comes up.

Comment: print `x_values` and `y_values` and post it here. It may just be an issue with your axis limits not being what you intend.

Comment: @NickilMaveli i saved the image but no plot comes up. it looks just like the window. only axis labels. i added the x and y values

Comment: First of all I'm confused on your output of the `x` and `y` values. Why are the `x_values` tuples or something, which already contain the `y` values? Fix that first of all. Both the `x` and `y` arrays should be just that, lists or numpy arrays or similar object. The `x` axis is labeled as years, yet the `y_values` seem to actually be an array of years. Totally inconsistent.

Secondly, I see no values in your output that are in the range `[0,0.08]`, which you have set for your `ylim`. Your data is just way out of bounds of your axes.

Answer (score 0):

Your upper y axis limit is 0.08 but your y values are in the range of 9-19.